# How best to code an Undo function in SpriteKit?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I'm creating a sprite-kit based game that allows players to build buildings. I'd like to create an undo button that goes back a step if a player places a block and makes an entire building fall apart.

I was considering a method where just before they place something the sprite-kit scene is saved, and if they tap "Undo" it will replace the scene with the previously saved scene.

Is this the best method to use, and the best method for minimising memory usage? Is there something prebuilt into spite-kit that could be used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a specific **UNDO** technic prebuilt in `sprite-kit`. My advice to save memory and performance is to build a stack of the user actions. You can make something like:

```
public struct Stack<T> {
    fileprivate var array = [T]()

    public var count: Int {
        return array.count
    }

    public var isEmpty: Bool {
        return array.isEmpty
    }

    public mutating func push(_ element: T) {
        array.append(element)
    }

    public mutating func pop() -> T? {
        return array.popLast()
    }

    public var top: T? {
        return array.last
    }
}
enum ActionType:String {
    case remove, add, moveTo, scale, rotate // add all the available user actions
}
struct UserAction {
    var type: ActionType
    var objectName: String
}
```

So, first of all you can create the LIFO (*last-in first-out* order) where the element you pushed last is the first one to come off with the next pop. Then you can create your custom LIFO element called in this example `UserAction` where you save the kind of action (*remove, add, rotate..*) and the `name` property of the object involved (for example if you have an `SKSpriteNode` called `box1` you should implement also `box1.name = "box1"` just to identify your involved node.

### Usage:

```
var undoArray = Stack(array:[])
let currentAction = UserAction.init(type: .remove, objectName: "box1")
print(" - User has \(currentAction.type.rawValue) the \(currentAction.objectName)")
undoArray.push(currentAction)
```

Obviously, this is only the UNDO array implementation. Your next step should be to build every single action like remove, add, rotate, to replicate the user action.

In other words to make another example when the user press the UNDO button you should "popping" an element from your stack:

```
// ...

if let lastEl = undoArray.pop() {
    let lastUserAction = lastEl as! UserAction
    switch lastUserAction.type {
    case .remove: print("replicate remove action")
    case .add: print("replicate add action")
    case .moveTo : print("replicate moveTo action")
    // ... add the other user actions
    default:break
    }
}
```

Comment: I have a feeling the way he is talking that he is using physics, so it goes beyond just saving actions.  My guess is it is like a Jenga tower, and when you remove a block from the Jenga tower, the tower may fall.  He wants to undo the falling so that the Jenga tower stands upright again.

Comment: Oh sure, I've understand what you mean, I agree with you. If you have something up the tower involved to phisic laws probably if you remove a block your tower hangs on one side and that object falling down to the ground: at this point UNDO actions are not enough, but it just be only an example, you can also build instead of `lastUserAction` something like `lastObjectState` where you store name, position and physics params before the user start a new action, I mean more info about the current state. That solution only when someone prefer to avoid to duplicate scenes as you correctly showed

Comment: What about creating a local array of the SKNodes in the scene and every time the user does something all the nodes in the scene get added as an array to that array. And when you hit undo, it removes the last added item of the array and replaces all the self.children with the last array in the nodes array?

Comment: Yeah, it could be a solution, depend by your game.Usually you should avoid to "save" big portions of data if these operations must be happened many times during the game. It's preferable to store strings or "pointers" to your data , not the full objects (suppose you have a node with different textures, atlas, it could be a big amount of memory occupied).What's your case?

Answer (score 0):

I would just make a copy of your GameScene, then when you need to undo, just reload the copy.

```
let copy = scene.copy() as? GameScene


view.presentScene(copy)
```

I wouldn't focus too hard on memory consumption unless you start seeing a problem.  The thing we sometimes tend to do is over optimize to the point that there is no return on investment (ROI). As long as you are not mismanaging objects you are retaining or creating zombies, you should not see too much problem with using this method.